# Terraform GCP Kubernetes: Unable to create Secrets using kubernetes_secret

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, kubernetes-secrets

I had created a private cluster with private endpoint enabled using Google provider. But ended up with below error while creating secrets using Kubernetes provider.

> kubernetes_secret.create-secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create secrets in the namespace "default"

Also, the state file doesn't contain master auth details like username, password, private key, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have RBAC enabled? If so by default your cluster should not allow full, unprivileged access any more. It seems like issue with clusterrolebinding. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/apiserver-builder/issues/225) is a similar reported issue got resolved upon creating clusterrolebinding for Anonymous requests. You can try the solution advised there and should resolve your problem.